# C# Instantiate IList object from a class and set local properties in one line

Tags: c#, list, instantiation

Hey wonderful stackoverflowers,
I'm having some trouble with the IList object that is part of a class.
It will later be serialized into JSON where the requirement is that it will produce an array with key value pairs inside of the customfield_10304 object.

Being used to working with Dictionaries for the similar purpose I'm trial-and-erroring away at doing something similar with an IList but failing.

```cs
            public class Customfield
            {
                public string self { get; set; }
                public string value { get; set; }
                public string id { get; set; }
            }
            public class RequestFieldValues
            {
                public IList<Customfield> customfield_10304 { get; set; }
            }

/* NOTE: This is how I THINK it should work in my mind, but it is throwing errors */
var customfield_10304 = new IList<string> { {value = "test", id = 0} }
```

What's a good way to approach this? Please guide me into the most appropriate solution.

Thank you in advance

Comment: U can't create an instance of an interface. Try creating an instance of a class that implements IList like List. Check out the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist?view=netcore-3.1) for classes  that implement IList

Comment: For serialising into JSON, please refer these Links [newtonJson](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm) and [Serialization in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to). Also JSon serialisation generates key-value pairs that are not analogous to Dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to achieve something like this?

```
        new RequestFieldValues()
            .customfield_10304 = new List<Customfield>
            {
                new Customfield{id ="id1", self = "Sefd1", value = "value1"},
                new Customfield{id ="id2", self = "Sefd2", value = "value2"}
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

So I kind of wrapped my head around the actual requirement of the JSON serialization and skipped thinking about Lists.

Came up with this

```cs
public Customfield[] customfield_10304 { get; set; }
requestFieldValues = new RequestFieldValues
                {
                    customfield_10304 = new Customfield[] 
                        {
                            new Customfield { value = "Other" }
                        }
                }
```

So I could make another instance of a String array and that works for the json output that I needed. It is thanks to @neelesh tip that I found out about this!